# How to make a loop that creates a new variable/object each iteration?

Tags: c++, loops

I'm doing a pool game simulation in the console. There's a class called Ball. Basically, I want the user to input how many pool balls there are on the table and what position and velocity they have. The only way I can see this working is if I use a loop from 1 (or 0) to the number of pool balls with the contents below in the loop. There are two problems with this, though

Problem 1: I do not know how to make it create a variable for every loop

Problem 2: Because it's in a loop, it'd only create the variables in the code block in the loop, meaning I can't use it outside of it.

```
cout << "Please tell me where to drop the ball (x y z): ";
int xp,yp,zp;
cin >> xp >> yp >> zp;
if (!cin) exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
vec3 position(xp,yp,zp);
cout << "Please tell me how fast the ball is moving (x y z): ";
int xv,yv,zv;
cin >> xv >> yv >> zv;
vec3 velocity(xv,yv,zv);
cout << "Please tell me how heavy the ball is: ";
int weight;
cin >> weight;
cout << "Please tell me what number the ball is: ";
int number;
cin >> number;
Ball my_ball(number,weight,position,velocity);
```

What do?

Comment: There are just too many possible ways, but one simple way is to put the balls in a `std::vector`. You can use its `push_back` method to add to the end. Declare that vector before the loop.

Answer (score 0):

Use a container (a `vector` for example) and store the objects within that container.

Read upon STL. It offers a useful libraries of containers, algorithms and other functionalities.

Answer (score 0):

Use `vector` to make a collection of `Ball`s:

```
vector<Ball> balls;

for (;;)
{
   // …
   balls.emplace_back(number, weight, position, velocity);
   // or:
   balls.push_back(Ball(number, weight, position, velocity));
}
```

`emplace_back` constructs a new element at the end of the `vector`, passing the provided arguments to the `Ball` constructor.